# Time complexity to convert a truth table to a boolean circuit

Tags: np-complete, np, satisfiability, search-problem

The SAT problem is often explained in terms of truth tables. Given some random boolean circuit, calculate its truth table; does there exist an output of $1$ in the truth table?

But how about going the other way? A function problem that inputs a truth table, and asks you to construct a boolean circuit that computes that truth table. Is this NP? Is it P?

Comment: It is neither, because it is not a decision problem.

Comment: It seems a rather trivial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A truth table for $m$ variables has $n=2^m$ entries. A corresponding sum-of-products expression is made of at most $2^m$ terms, each of length $m$. So the total complexity of outputting them is $O(m2^m)=O(n\log n)$, in terms of the input size. This is polynomial.

---

As regards minimization of the expression, a possible approach is the Quine–McCluskey algorithm. From Wikipedia "For a function of $m$ variables the number of prime implicants can be as large as $\dfrac{3^{m}}{\sqrt {m}}$", which is $O(n^{\log3/\log2})$, still polynomial. Then "Step two of the algorithm amounts to solving the set cover problem, which is NP-hard". But I could not find an explicit expression of the complexity of the latter.

Comment: (in case the algorithm wasn't clear: it outputs one AND gate for each line in the truth table where the output is 1, then ORs them all together)

Comment: @user253751: the cost of "outputting an AND gate" is unclear; it could be considered to be constant. My answer goes in the way of writing down the formula.